# Use the contents of a file as a form field with curl

Tags: bash, curl

I need to create a curl request where one of the form fields is the contents of a file. Note, I do not want to upload the file as a file, I need the form field to be the content of the file. The file contains newlines and other potentially problematic characters.

This is what I have so far:
`curl -X POST -F "description=$(cat TEST/README.txt)" https://httpbin.org/post`

But this causes warnings like:

```
Warning: skip unknown form field: Sed varius sapien eget auctor mattis. Nunc
...
```

This works as expected, but the caveat being its static content, not the file I desire: `curl -X POST -F $'description=hi\nthere\n\n\n\nbud' https://httpbin.org/post`

Comment: I just realized that my input has a semicolon and thats the issue; still don't know how to esape it

Comment: Does `curl -X POST --data-urlencode "description@TEST/README.txt" https://httpbin.org/post` do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with semicolons, not newlines. `--form-string` Solved my issue